# Modify DataFrame index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a wrong DateTimeIndex. The hours and minutes must be moved to the left:

2016-07-07 00:08:30
->
2016-07-07 08:30:00

I know how to make the change with regex, but I do not know how to replace the index by the modified one. Something like df.index.replace(lambda old_index:new_index)...

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

By using `to_datetime` with `format`

```
#idx=pd.Index(pd.to_datetime(pd.Series('2016-07-07 00:08:30')))

pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(idx).astype(str),format='%Y-%m-%d %S:%H:%M')
Out[562]: 
0   2016-07-07 08:30:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And for new index use:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.astype(str),format='%Y-%m-%d %S:%H:%M')
```

Comment: And how can I apply that to the index of my DataFrame?